# Android View doesn't become VISIBLE

Tags: android, layout, view, onclick, visibility

I'm trying to implement controls for my music player.

Here is my XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        ...

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/control_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4">

<!-- This is volume control Button -->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_control_volume_container"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_control_volume"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/item_bg_transparent"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_volume_up_black_24dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

<!-- Other Buttons -->
                ...
            </LinearLayout>

<!-- Layout with volume control SeekBar -->
            <io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/reveal_seek_bar_volume"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container_seek_bar_volume"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/container_seek_bar_volume_close"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/item_bg_transparent"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/seek_bar_volume"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:max="100"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="0dp"
                        android:progress="100"
                        app:theme="@style/AppTheme.SeekBar.Accent" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And my code:

```
LLcontainerSBvolume = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_seek_bar_volume);
IBcontrolVolume = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_control_volume);
        IBcontrolVolume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LLcontainerSBvolume.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

I also tried to request focus for `ImageButton` and other `Views`:

```
IBcontrolVolume.requestFocus();
LLcontainerSBvolume.requestFocus();
LLcontainerSBvolume.requestLayout();
```

**PROBLEM**

The problem is next:

When I start my `Activity`, click on song, open `BottomSheet` and click volume control `ImageButton`, `Seekbar` not becomes `VISIBLE`. I should click on other `View` and then volume `ImageButton` works as well.

Comment: Why are you making whole `container_seek_bar_volume` view GONE, Instead of applying it to only `seek_bar_volume`

Comment: @ShreeKrishna, yes, because there is also close `ImageButton` near `SeekBar`

Comment: you want both be invisible at first start and make visible pragmatically. Then both became visible or only one became visible ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna, I tried to set visibily `GONE` to `ImageButton` and `SeekBar` separately and setting `INVISIBLE` to LLcontainerSBvolume instead of `GONE` and it works great. Thank you for idea (: . But I still can't understand what's wrong with making `ViewGroup` `GONE`...

Comment: @ShreeKrishna, maybe you're right. Yes, of course, add it. I'll accept.

Comment: Thanks bro.. It's my pleasure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Layout that you are setting `Visibility` to `GONE` at the startup and making it visible at runtime are not Inside formal android `Layout`. Its inside custom library `io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout` which may have bugs in changing `Visibility` at runtime. So don't use `android:visibility` in the container of your `ImageButton` and `AppCompatSeekBar`. Do it separately Like

```
<ImageButton
  -----
android:visibility="gone" />


<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
   -----
android:visibility="gone" />
```

**Then inside `onClick` make both visible or one visible as your requirements like here**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   myImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   myAppCompatSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```